# jQuery datepicker - Why is theme styling not showing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've used jQuery to make a datepicker like so:

```
<input type="text" id="my_datepicker">
```

and

```
$('#my_datepicker').datepicker();
```

The datepicker is working fine and I have used this several times before. The issue is that the input element still looks like a normal text field, whereas when I have used this in the past, it has used jQuery UI classes to style the field so that it looks glossy and in keeping with the theme.

I have used firebug to see which clesses have been applied to the input element, and it only has:

```
hasDatepicker
```

whereas a the input field of a datepicker on another site that is styled correctly has all of the following classes:

```
hasDatepicker
ui-inputfield
ui-widget 
ui-state-default
ui-corner-all
```

I've looked at the datepicker docs, but I can't see an option that lets you opt in or out of this styling and I would have thought that this happen by default anyway.

Can anyone show me what I need to do to enable this?

Many thanks.

**Update**:

```
<input id="dob" type="text" maxlength="45" size="45" />
```

This is the input markup from the live site as requested.

Comment: make sure that you have included css in your page

Comment: Well, you could always just [add those classes yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/WHeEy/). Can we see the source of the `input` in the working site, please?

Comment: @Matt Hi there. I've made an edit to my post to show the actual `input` from the live site.

Comment: @Senad Hi. I have checked and all the CSS is there. All the other components are being themed fine. In fact, as I'm developing I've just used the css and js file which contains everything.

Comment: can you give us location, so we can see it

Comment: Hi. I know it makes it more difficult, but I'd rather not do that. I think I'll do as Matt has suggested and just add the classes myself. I just thought these would be added automatically. Thanks for your help and comments. Appreciate it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what versions of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using on these different pages? I'm wondering whether there's been a change...

Comment: @Matt - I'm using version 1.5.1 of jQuery and version 1.8.15 of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 21):

Are you linking in the theme stylesheet?

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"    />
```

Comment: I had accidentally used media="screen", which prevented the styling from being applied? WEIRD! Switching to media="all" applied the styling as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the site that you point out is applying the css styles to the input field apart from the jquery-ui library, I mean, in a stylesheet that don't belongs to jquery-ui.

In this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/diosney/PkEar/3/ you can see that these classes are not applied by jquery-ui datepicker() itself (I'm using jquery 1.6.2 and jquery-ui 1.8.14).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was coming from how my application was bundling the css files. I added links in my index page and was able to get the themes working.

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

let's try with bellow 
For admin : -

```
    function eds_admin_styles() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-datepicker-style' , '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
    }
    add_action('admin_print_styles', 'eds_admin_styles');
    function eds_admin_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    }
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'eds_admin_scripts');
```

For theme:

```
    function edsbootstrap_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-datepicker-style' , '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'edsbootstrap_scripts' );
```

here is js

```
   (function($) {
      $('#jquery-datepicker').datepicker();
    }(jQuery));
```