# Date Picker lose styles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I try to add date picker on my form :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateTo, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTo, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "End Date"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

I install jquery-ui and init date pickers as :     `$('.datepicker').datepicker();`

As Result i get this :

[image]

Where is problem?

Comment: Did you include the jquery ui css file?

Comment: did you include the jquery-ui-css file ?

Comment: Please have mercy on us , provide your jsFiddle , I cant see your code in YOUR PC ! :(

Comment: @sliedtoad, goo timing... :) no need to code AngryBird, File missing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147745/jquery-datepicker-why-is-theme-styling-not-showing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111132/jquery-ui-datepicker-is-missing-style-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your head tag:

Please read documentation and usage of a plugin before implementing to save time.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

Styles for data picker and other plugins are written in this file.